# Pandas dataframe vertical merge

Tags: python, pandas

I have a query regarding merging two dataframes
For example i have 2 dataframes as below :

```
print(df1)

   Year   Location  
0  2013    america     
1  2008     usa       
2  2011     asia   



print(df2)

   Year Location  
0  2008      usa       
1  2008      usa       
2  2009     asia
```

My expected output :

```
Year   Location  
2013    america     
2008     usa       
2011     asia

Year   Location
2008      usa       
2008      usa       
2009     asia
```

Output i am getting right now :

```
Year   Location    Year   Location
2013   america    2008    usa
2008    usa       2008    usa
2011    asia      2009    asia
```

I have tried using `pd.concat` and `pd.merge` with no luck

Please help me with above

Comment: "*I have tried using pd.concat and pd.merge with no luck"* Please post the code for your attempts.  `pd.concat` is what you should be using.

Answer (score 3):

Simply specify the axis along which to concatenate (`axis=1`) in `pd.concat`:

```
df_merged=pd.concat([df1,df2],axis=1)
```

Comment: You don't want `axis=1` for this use case.

Answer (score 2):

`pd.concat([df1, df2])` should work.  If all the column headings are the same, it will bind the second dataframe's rows below the first.  This graphic from a pandas cheat sheet (https://pandas.pydata.org/Pandas_Cheat_Sheet.pdf) explains it pretty well:
[image]

Comment: Not really sure how this is different than the other answers . . .

Comment: The other answers were not part of my review queue. Adding an explanation as to why you snippet would answer the question will only benefit others down the road having the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

It's the same columns and same order, so that you can use: `df1.append(df2)`

Comment: I have Tried it but it is also appending horizontally

Answer (score 0):

```
output_df = pd.concat([df1, df2], ignore_index=False)
```

if you'd set ignore_index = True, you lost your original indexes and get 0..n-1 instead

It works for MultiIndex too